# How to make a link title the same as its URL using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My goal is to make the title of every external link equal to its href attribute.

My question is, how can I make the `title` variable available to the `attr` function?

```
$('a').filter(function() {

    var title= $(this).attr('href');
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;

 })
    .removeAttr('target')
    .attr('rel', 'external')
    .attr('title', title);

$('a[rel="external"]').click( function() {
    window.open( $(this).attr('href') );
    return false;
});
```

I think I somehow have it backwards, and the answer is in [attr(key, fn)](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyfn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname) {
        $(this).removeAttr('target')
               .attr('rel', 'external')
               .attr('title', href)
               .click(function() {
                   window.open(href);
                   return false;
               });
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to combine this with the click function?

Comment: I changed it. There really is no need to bind a click event to it, though, I'm not sure why you want to do it this way. But I'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: Our external links should open in their own window. I'd prefer not but rules is rules. Thanks again :)